# Python memory issues - memory doesn't get released after finishing a method

Tags: python, memory

I have a quite complex python (2.7 on ubuntu) code which is leaking memory unexpectedly. To break it down, it is a method which is repeatedly called (and itself calls different methods) and returns a very small object. After finishing the method the used memory is not released. As far as I know it is not unusual to reserve some memory for later usages, but if I use big enough input my machine eventually consumes all memory and freezes. This is not the case if I use a subprocess with concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor, thus I need to assume it is not my code but some underlying problems?!

Is this a known issue? Might it be a problem in 3rd party libraries I am using (e.g. PyQgis)? Where should I start to search for the problem?

Some more Background to eliminate silly reasons (because I am still somewhat of a beginner):

The method uses some global variables but in my understanding these should only be active in the file where they are declared and anyways should be overwritten in the next call of the method?!
To clarify in pseudocode:

```
def main():
    load input from file
    for x in input:
        result = extra_file.initialization(x)
        #here is the point where memory should get released in my opinion

#extra file
def initialization(x):
    global input
    input = x
    result_container = []
    while not result do:
        part_of_result = method1()
        result_container.append(part_of_result)
        if result_container fulfills condition to be the final result:
            result = result_container
    del input
    return result

def method1():
    #do stuff
    method2()
    #do stuff
    return part_of_result

def method2():
    #do stuff with input not altering it
```

Numerous different methods and global variables are involved and the global declaration is used to not pass like 5 different input variables through multiple methods which don't even use them.

Should I try using garbage collection? All references after finishing the method should be deleted and python itself should take care of it?

Comment: "understanding these should only be active in the file where they are declared" no. That's not how programs work at all. Scope is lexical in Python, and global scope is really module scope, but program memory is shared across th entire running process. You need to provide us with a [mcve] otherwise only speculation is possible

Comment: I edited some pseudocode into it and hope this clarifys the global usage. Sadly it is not possible to deliver a minimal, complete and verifiable example of 2000 lines of code. And I don't assume anyone wanna review all my code, therefore I am asking if my comprehension of python and what it should do under the described circumstances is correct.

Comment: @gilla: What memory are you expecting to be released? The input from the file? You stored it in a global variable in `extra_file` as part of the call to `initialization`, intentionally. So at least some of the file is going to stay in memory. The pseudo-code is clearly nonsense (part of result is assigned to the result if it's already equal to the result???), so I can't give more detail, but clearly you're storing persistent references that exist beyond the scope of the functions, which doesn't give me confidence the rest of the code isn't saving off data forever in other ways.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes that was obviously bad pseudo code. I've corrected it. Also yes you're right it wouldn't get released after finishing the method but it should get released when again calling the method and overwriting extra_file.input. In my understanding extra_file.input can't exist multiple times or am I wrong? So as expected deleting input before returning the result (also edited in) does not change anything as well.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely try using garbage collection. I don't believe it's a known problem.

Comment: Garbage collection is on by default.